# Mesos API for starting and stopping Slave nodes

Tags: apache, docker, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

Wanted to check if any of you uses Mesos API to start and stop the Slave nodes.

I see Mesos API has some options to check the status of slaves, but not sure whether it will allow shutdown from an API.

http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/endpoints/master/machine/down/

Comment: As far as I know there are no endpoints to actually start/stop agents via an API in Mesos.

Comment: Thanks.  When i use below end point, I do see some attributes which says scheduled_slave_shutdown, so was curious if Mesos has any endpoint to control the behaviour of slaves.                                              /metrics/snapshot